# Can I lowercase all the /home/$USER/ directories that start with an uppercase letter?

Tags: nautilus, ubuntu-mate, xdg, caja

`~/Pictures`, `~/Downloads`, `~/Desktop`, `~/Documents`, etc. These are some of the only uppercase directories on my system, and I usually type `~/pictures` forgetting that the first letter has to be uppercase.

Of course I can rename the folders themselves but then applications that require these folders will not work properly. For example Caja (or Nautilus) displays on the desktop the contents of the `~/Desktop` folder.

Where is the configuration file that tells the desktop environment the name of the desktop folder?

The user media folders like Downloads and Pictures also have special folder icons associated with them which I quite like. If I would rename `~/Downloads` to `~/downloads` the folder is no longer "special" to the file manager.

I guess the question is about specific desktop envrionments and their configuration, but isn't this all usually governed by the FreeDesktop specifications?

So there must be a FreeDesktop configuration file somewhere on the system that all applications go through when they want to find my Pictures or Downloads or Desktop folder.

Where is that configuration file?

Comment: I'm sure  you could do it by why would you deviate from the universal format established by MS Windows and adopted by Linux? If you lived in a bubble and never used another machine in the world you would be comfortable, but if you ventured outside your bubble you would be frustrated by the upper-case everyone else is using.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix On the contrary I'm looking to do because of how frustratingly deviant capitalization is here. Of the thousands of files linux has by default only these half dozen aren't all lowercase, it doesn't make any sense, you can't just half adopt a policy. On Windows, almost all files are capitalized, so it's still self consistent.

Comment: @NicholasPipitone Old Linux maybe. Take a look at the newer systemd stuff `NetworkManager` instead of `network-manager`. Personally I'm flexible and use both methods. I respect people's preference for having only one method or the other though.